# Android "Receiving a broadcast in package xxx requires a permissions review"

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-testing

I have two applications, one will send a broadcast with ***a customized action*** "com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo.action.INFORM_TIME", the other application with a broadcast receiver registered in JUnit @Before class.
This receiver works well on android Pie, but not working on android Q.
From logcat, it says "**Receiving a broadcast in package xxx requires a permissions review**". "xxx" stands for the JUnit test package.

- Android Pie broadcast receiver works fine, android Q JUnit test doesn't.
- Android Q application (with a visible UI) broadcast receiver works fine, android Q JUnit test broadcast receiver won't work.
- Use `adb install -g xxx` to install the two JUnit test applications on andorid Q, broadcast receiver works fine. Without `-g`, not working. So it seems to be a permission issue.

Application A sends broadcast:

```
Intent informIntent = new Intent();   informIntent.setAction("com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo.action.INFORM_TIME");
informIntent.putExtra("Time", time);
sendBroadcast(informIntent);
```

Application B receives broadcast:

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action != null && action.equals(ACTION_INFORM_TIME)) {
                    Long currentTime = intent.getLongExtra("Time", -1);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: Receives current Exoplayer playback time '" + currentTime + "'.");
                    time = currentTime;
                }
            }
        };
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo.action.INFORM_TIME");
mContext.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

I'm not quite sure what are the differences on broadcast receiver between android Pie and android Q, between application with user visible UI and JUnit test.
**The question is, what permission do we need to receive a broadcast with a customized action.**
Need help, any comment will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause, on android Pie devices, `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission works well, I can safely directly write to folder `/sdcard/`. But on android Q, this won't work any more.

So this writing file failure somehow make my broadcast receiver fail to receive any broadcasts. Unbelievable!!!

Bu that's it, after I update my folder for saving files and remove the permission `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in manifest, broadcast receiver works fine now android Q.

Comment: Fond the same issue, lack of declaring permission "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" also leads to BroadcastReceiver not working, logcat shows `Receiving a broadcast in package xxx requires a permissions review`.  

After declaring and granting the permission manually, the BroadcastReceiver works well.